# Self Association in Rails with adding foreign key error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing self association in rails. I have Request model which should reference itself. Here is what i have:

```html
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :sub_requests, class_name: 'Request',
                          foreign_key: 'parent_request_id'

  belongs_to :parent_request, class_name: 'Request'

end
```

and my migration:

```html
class CreateRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :requests do |t|
      t.references :parent_request, index: true
  
    end
  end
end
```

But I get an error as follows:

```html
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column requests.parent_request_id does not exist
```

Comment: Does your db schema show it?  If you view the table through postgres does that column exist?  Did you run the migration?

Comment: check the output of `rake db:migrate:status` I think migration is pending.

Comment: After running the migration, please also restart the server..

Answer (score 0):

Have you run rake db:migrate? If you did, than try this one:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sub_requests, class_name: 'Request', foreign_key: 'parent_request_id', primary_key: 'id'
  belongs_to :parent_request, class_name: 'Request', foreign_key: 'parent_request_id', primary_key: 'id'
end

class CreateRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :requests do |t|
      t.integer :parent_request_id, index: true
    end
  end
end
```